How to list operations recorded by TensorFlow GradientTape
I'd like to print out all the steps that a GradientTape is recording during the forward pass.
As a simple example I've created the following code that implements a single training step on a single neuron.
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def one_training_step(X, y, loss_fn, activation_fn):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_ = activation_fn(X @ w + b)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, [w, b])
    print(f"Watched: {tape.watched_variables()}")
    print(f"Grads: {grads}")

X = tf.constant([[1.0]], dtype=float, name='X')
y = tf.constant([[1.0]], dtype=float, name='y')
w = tf.Variable([[2.0]], dtype=float, name='w')
b = tf.Variable([[3.0]], dtype=float, name='b')
activation_fn = tf.keras.activations.get('sigmoid')
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
one_training_step(X, y, loss_fn, activation_fn)

The output is as follows:
Watched: (<tf.Variable 'w:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'b:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>)
Grads: [<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/matmul/MatMul:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>]

This seems to indicate the matrix multiplication for w and the addition for b.
But what happened to the other differentiable calculations - the activation function and the loss?
I'd like to get a list of all the steps that the gradient tape has recorded during the forward pass. This is important because I'm investigating custom neural networks (e.g. those with recursive connections) and I want to work out what calculations are being applied to give the gradient.
